# No Reporting Server connect option in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssms

I'm trying to connect to our SSRS reporting server, but in my local SSMS, the Connect drop-down on Object Explorer only lists Database Engine and SQL Server Compact.  I only installed SSMS this week, so do I need any additional installs or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Management Studio Express cannot manage reporting services, you need the full version SSMS for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx